# Returning a binary tree to a var

Tags: c#, return, binary-tree

I have an exercise I was working on using binary trees where there are two functions that you use and they look like the following:

```
class Program
{
    public Node root;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //build and return tree
        var b = binaryTree();

        //get sum of tree
        var x = binaryTreeSum(b);
        //Console.WriteLine("Sum of the binary tree is " + x);

    }
```

I am getting an error on the `var b = binaryTreeSum(b)` object reference is required for a non-static field, method, or property. I was trying to create my tree in the following function:

```
    public Program binaryTree()
    {
        //build tree
        Program tree = new Program();

        tree.root = new Node(10);
        tree.root.left = new Node(5);
        tree.root.right = new Node(11);
        tree.root.left.left = new Node(2);
        tree.root.left.right = new Node(1);
        tree.root.right.left = new Node(5);
        tree.root.right.right = new Node(123);

       return tree;
    }
```

Is there a way to return my `tree.root` or `tree` to `var b`? I know I can use `tree.root` to get the sum in the next function which is what I am trying to do. I may be going about this all wrong to begin with but I have to use those two functions and return to the `var`

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are already returning the tree. Your code doesn't ever define an "a", only "b" (var b = binaryTree()). Are you getting an error? What behavior are you seeing which isn't what you expect?

Comment: `Program` sounds like a *really* bad name for a class that represents a binary tree.  I'd suggest using something like `BinaryTree` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to `return tree;`
According to your method signature, you want to return a `BinaryTree` object, but you are currently attempting to return a `Node`.

As I'm not sure where those objects came from (you created them?) I'm assuming that one does not derive from the other.

The return from your `binaryTree()` function will automatically be assigned to `var a`